# Primitive Graphic Animation in Android using ImageView? Edited

Tags: java, android, animation, graphics, drawing

Admitted noob at android/java.  Say I wanted to use very simple graphic line commands (canvas.drawLine(args...)) to show an animated sweep second hand of a clock moving through time.  How would I go about redrawing/updating the line every second, presumably using a canvas, imageview, and bitmap?

Asked another way, how would I animate a simple line moving across an ImageView in Android?

Have tried creating a "CustomView" extended version of ImageView and placing some code in its overridden onDraw() method, and have tried some threading, but usually only get the final position of the line segment drawn.  None of the intermediate positions appear.  Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.